# Error while importing config file in Ember Addon

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am working on an addon for Ember but I can't find the right way to import the config file.

I currently import the config file that way, from my service:

```
import ENV from '../config/environment';
```

I am testing the addon from the `dummy/app` folder, but when I try to use my service, I get the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Could not find module
>   `ember-my-addon/config/environment` imported from
>   `ember-my-addon/services/my-service`

It should grab the config file from the `dummy/app/config/environment.js`, or the config file of the app that installed the addon.

What would be the best practice to import this file?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the addon [ember-get-config](https://github.com/null-null-null/ember-get-config)

Alternatively, you can use the solution posted here:

http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/best-practices-accessing-app-config-from-addon-code/7006/19?u=gaurav0

Comment: I took a look to this addon, but using `window.requirejs` to import the file, seriously? There isn't a better way?

Comment: You can also use container.lookup("config:environment") but that uses a private API as well.

Comment: Wasn't this deprecated?

Comment: what about `getOwner`?